# How to collapse row table when size get min width on resize

Tags: html, html-table, responsive

I am trying to create a simple responsive table (only with one row).

```
                <table style={{'width': '100%'}}>
                    <tr>
                        <th style={{'width': '25%', minWidth: 200, background: 'red'}}>25%</th>
                        <th style={{'width': '5%', minWidth: 40, background: 'blue'}}>5%</th>
                        <th style={{'width': '25%', minWidth: 200, background: 'red'}}>25%</th>
                        <th style={{'width': '17%', minWidth: 136, background: 'blue'}}>17%</th>
                        <th style={{'width': '17%', minWidth: 136, background: 'red'}}>17%</th>
                        <th style={{'width': '11%', minWidth: 88, background: 'blue'}}>11%</th>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

So, my goal is collapse row (row per line) when I resize the window to smaller.

Actual state:

```
25% | 5% | 25% | 17% | 17 % | 11%
```

expected state on window resize

```
25%
---
5%
---
25%
---
17%
---
17%
---
11%
```

So, if there is a better way (for example using div) tell me how.

Thank you for any help.
(Note: **I have only one row** - so I think that table is not optimal)

Thank you for any help.

(It is React syntax)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand correctly, but you could simply use divs and apply flex ad flex-direction to the parent, along basic with media queries:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div style={{'width': '25%', minWidth: 200, background: 'red'}}>25%</div>
    ...
</div>
```

Ad apply it something along the lines of:

```
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;      /* display on top of each other */
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .wrapper > * {
        width: 100% !important;  /* might be required in order to override inline styles */
    }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {      /* on screens larger than 768px */
    .wrapper {
        flex-direction: row;     /* display next to each other */
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this. I have a similar solution for larger data tables, but that works great for something this small.

Answer (score -1):

Its better to use internal or external css with setting the `id` of each `th`.

Check this: https://jsfiddle.net/dr42wqaz/

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#Mytable {
  width: 100%;
}
#Fth {
  width: 25%;
  min-Width: 200px;
  background: red;
}
#Sth {
  width: 5%;
  min-Width: 40px;
  background: blue;
}
#Tth {
  width: 25%;
  min-Width: 200px;
  background: red;
}
#FRth {
  width: 17%;
  min-Width: 136px;
  background: blue;
}
#FTth {
  width: 17%;
  min-Width: 136px;
  background: red;
}
#SXth {
  width: 11%;
  min-Width: 88px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<table id="Mytable">
  <tr>
    <th id="Fth">25%</th>
    <th id="Sth">5%</th>
    <th id="Tth">25%</th>
    <th id="FRth">17%</th>
    <th id="FTth">17%</th>
    <th id="SXth">11%</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```